# Save the results of get request in a local file

Tags: python, api, rest, file, flask

I have a Flask app in Python that sends a request to an API and renders the results on the webpage. Just before rendering the results, I want to save them to a CSV file locally.

Function for sending the request to the API:

```
def search_query(search_text):
    try:

        # Create a search client
        azure_credential = AzureKeyCredential(search_key)
        search_client = SearchClient(search_endpoint, search_index, azure_credential)

        # Submit search query
        results = search_client.search(search_text)

        return results
    except Exception as ex:
        raise ex
```

Function for saving the results to a local file:

```
def save_results(search_text, results):
    for result in results:
        with open('search_results.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
            writer = csv.writer(file)
            writer.writerow([search_text,result['metadata_storage_name'],
result['@search.score']])
        file.close()
```

Function to render the results on HTML:

```
@app.route("/search", methods=['GET'])
def search():

        # Get the search terms from the request form
        search_text = request.args["search"]


        # submit the query and get the results
        results = search_query(search_text)
        
        # Call the function to save the result
        save_results(search_text, results)
           
        # render the results
        return render_template("search.html", search_results=results, search_terms=search_text)
```

With the functions shown above, first I tried to render without saving the results, it works well. But if I save the results before rendering, then the results don't get rendered on the page.

How can I do both in the same app?